# How to place a table to the right of an image in iText7

Tags: itext, alignment

In creating a pdf file using iText7, I am trying to get a table to sit to the right of a chart. Currently they are taking up the correct sizing but the top of the table on the right is in line with the bottom of the chart on the left instead of aligned with the top of the chart. I would appreciate any help in having the top of the chart and the top of the table horizontally aligned. My code is:

```
String absentChart = "./wwwroot/Images/Charts/" + formData.ReportId + "_AbsentChart.png";
ImageData absentData = ImageDataFactory.Create(absentChart);
Image absentImg = new Image(absentData).ScaleToFit(260, 200);
absentImg.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
document.Add(absentImg);

float[] columnWidths = { 20, 40, 20 };
Table absentTable = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(columnWidths));
absentTable.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).Add(new Paragraph(formData.SlaSameDate.ToString())));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).Add(new Paragraph("Same Day")));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).Add(new Paragraph(formData.SlaSameDatePcent.ToString() + "%")));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).Add(new Paragraph(formData.OneMonth.ToString())));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).Add(new Paragraph("Less than 1 Month")));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).Add(new Paragraph(formData.OneMonthPcent.ToString() + "%")));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).Add(new Paragraph(formData.OneToThreeMonth.ToString())));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).Add(new Paragraph("1 - 3 Months")));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).Add(new Paragraph(formData.OneToThreeMonthPcent.ToString() + "%")));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).Add(new Paragraph(formData.ThreeToEightMonth.ToString())));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).Add(new Paragraph("3 - 8 Months")));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).Add(new Paragraph(formData.ThreeToEightMonthPcent.ToString() + "%")));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).Add(new Paragraph(formData.NineToTwelveMonth.ToString())));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).Add(new Paragraph("9 - 12 Months")));
absentTable.AddCell(new Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).Add(new Paragraph(formData.NineToTwelveMonthPcent.ToString() + "%")));


document.Add(absentTable);
```